# ROR SQLIite text length

Tags: ruby

In my application I have a model, with a :string field containing a description. Everything works fine on my local machine, but heroku gives me an error message. I looked into logs and found the error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: ERROR:  value too long for
>   type character varying(255)

It's interesting because EXACTLY the same text works fine on my local machine. :P I found a suggestion on the web that I should generate a new migration changing :string format for :text format. I tried to do so like it was showed there:

```
change_column :your_table_name, :name_of_field, :string, :text
```

But got en error:

> -- change_column(:users, :about_me, :string, :text) rake aborted! An
>   error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
>
> undefined method `include?' for :text:Symbol

The question is how to make it work with long strings, and also for curiosity, why it works on local machine and crashes on heroku?

Thanks in advance

Bye

Comment: You should also stop developing on SQLite and deploying on PostgreSQL. All databases are a bit different and ActiveRecord won't protect you from those differences. You'll eventually run into GROUP BY problems as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's `change_column :your_table_name, :name_of_field, :text`
So, about the error. It's PostgreSQL's error. PGError: (`ERROR: value too long for type character varying(255)`) It means that heroku is using PostgreSQL but you are using SQLite on your local machine.

Comment: hey - i have this problem as well. What would be a solution for this?